# Magento2 Some product not showing in frontend

Tags: magento2, frontend, reindex, indexing, magento2.4.5

I have the problem that no products are listed in the categories in the frontend, although they are available and the index status in the backend is indicated as "Ready" for all indexers. Products are only listed in the frontend again when I perform a "php bin/magento indexer:reindex" command and clear the cache. The next day, however, they disappear again.
For references we have attach Screenshot.

- https://i.stack.imgur.com/nbQoT.png

We have using Magento version:- 2.4.5,PHP version:- 8.1,We use Server is:- A2 Hosting.

anyone idea of this issue?